# Getting function object for int() and float() functions

Tags: python, function

I want to pass a function to a function in Python. I know I can do this simply by putting the function name as a parameter, eg:

```
blah(5, function)
```

However, I want to pass the `int()` function and the `float()` function to this function. If I just put the function name in then it assumes I am referring to the `int` and `float` types not the functions for converting strings to ints and floats.

Is there a way to pass the function rather than the type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just passing `int` and `float` is fine.  You are right that this will actually pass type objects instead of functions, but that's not important.  The important thing is that the passed object is callable, and calling the type objects will do what you expect.

Comment: Why would you ever need to pass int as an argument?

Comment: @Trufa: Just two examples: `defaultdict(int)` and `map(int, string_list)`.  There are many more.

Comment: `sorted(['1','100','99'], key=int)`

Comment: I was not trying to be a smartass (if that is how it sounded), I was just curious :) . And I did not phrase my question correctly, my question was: why would you need to pass int as a function, as it will always be callable as `int()` as it is built in, rather you need to pass is as the type, as you stated in your examples, have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Trufa: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

The type objects *are* what you want.

```
>>> def converter(value, converter_func):
...     new_value = converter_func(value)
...     print new_value, type(new_value)
... 
>>> converter('1', int)
1 <type 'int'>
>>> converter('2.2', float)
2.2 <type 'float'>
>>>
```